# Upload a file to SharePoint document library using post man

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, postman

Need to upload a file to one document library SP2013 , and see the response in POSTMAN, using REST API, which format , which parameter to pass

Answer (score 0):

Here is a completed demo about uploading file using Rest API, read file stream and then upload

```
 var folderName = "Folder1";
    var targetUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/" + documentLibrary + "/" + folderName;
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(@target)/Files/add(overwrite=true, url='" + fileName + "')?$expand=ListItemAllFields @target='" + targetUrl + "'";

    uploadFileToFolder(uploadFileObj, url, function (data) {
        var file = data.d;
        var updateObject = {
            __metadata: {
                type: file.ListItemAllFields.__metadata.type
            },
            Column1: 'Test Data',   //meta data column1
            Column2: 'Test Data'    //meta data column2
        };

        url = webUrl + "/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('"+documentLibrary+"')/items(" + file.ListItemAllFields.Id + ")";

        updateFileMetadata(url, updateObject, file, function (data) {
            alert("File uploaded &amp;amp; meta data updation done successfully");
        }, function (data) {
            alert("File upload done but meta data updating FAILED");
        });
    }, function (data) {
        alert("File uploading and meta data updating FAILED");
    });
}

function getFileBuffer(uploadFile) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
    }
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        deferred.reject(e.target.error);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(uploadFile);
    return deferred.promise();
}

function uploadFileToFolder(fileObj, url, success, failure) {
    var apiUrl = url;
    var getFile = getFileBuffer(fileObj);
    getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {
        $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            },
            success: function (data) {
                success(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                failure(data);
            }
        });
    });
}

function updateFileMetadata(apiUrl, updateObject, file, success, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: apiUrl,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(updateObject),
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-Http-Method": "MERGE",
            "IF-MATCH": file.ListItemAllFields.__metadata.etag,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Save the code in a js file, upload to Site Assets, then reference it in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://tarundev.sharepoint.com/sites/sharepointmates/SharepointMates/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://tarundev.sharepoint.com/sites/sharepointmates/SharepointMates/Scripts/FileUploadScript.js"></script>

<input type="File" id="inputTypeFiles" />

<br>
<input type="button" id="btnUploadFiles" value="submit" Text="Upload"/>
```

Taken from here:
[Upload a file into document library using REST API in SharePoint 2013 / Online](https://sharepointmates.com/2017/07/20/upload-a-file-into-document-library-using-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2013-online/)

Comment: thanks ,
But i'm look for API response through POSTMAN

Comment: @Jerry_MSFT what if access token is needed for share point connection . here we don't have any option to provide access token .